# Check if the multiple csv files exist in the directory by using boolean but its not working

Tags: python

I have created a definition to check multiple files in directory. The objective is to execute this definition in further program. But its not working, even the files exists in directory. Please suggest.

```
import os
def is_file_exist():
    return (bool(os.path.exists(dir + 'file1.csv')),
            bool(os.path.exists(dir + 'file2.csv')),
            bool(os.path.exists(dir + 'file3.csv')))

if is_file_exist() == True:
    print('Do Something')
```

Comment: note that the return type of the function appears to be a `tuple` instead of bool. that is, the condition for the if might need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by the comments, you are returning a tuple and not a boolean. To check if all values in an iterable are true, you can use the `all()` method.

```py
import os
def is_file_exist():
    return all((bool(os.path.exists(dir + 'file1.csv')),
            bool(os.path.exists(dir + 'file2.csv')),
            bool(os.path.exists(dir + 'file3.csv'))))

if is_file_exist() == True:
    print('Do Something')
```

Comment: Thanks. Was missing 'all' in the function. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing is you are returning a tuple, which can have either `True` as elements or 'False' as elements or both.

So in all the cases, the tuple is non-empty, thus is a truthy.

Thus the condition is going to be true always.

Comment: Empty tuple will not be truthy. Its false.